# How to modify the code so that i do not have to uninstall pycharm?

Tags: exception, try-catch, python-3.8

I have run the code as part of exception handling in python, during a session on *Plural-sight* but now even if a write a incorrect code the result is OK.
For example : hello world without print statement gives me exit code 0

Could you please advice on it?

code :

```
try:
    import msvcrt

def getkey():
    return msvcrt.getch()


except ImportError:
    import sys
    import tty
    import termios
    def getkey():
        fd=sys.stdin.fileno()
        original_attributes =termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, original_attributes)
            return ch
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the indentation of your code is correct first.

For example `get_key` function should be defined in both: the `try` case and in the `catch`, in the `catch` case you indented  it correctly under the catch statement, but for the `try` case you made it on the same level of indentation as the `try` itself,  for the interpreter it means that the function definition is not related to the `try` you wrote, therefore it throws an error as you should not add code after between the try and catch statement.

a rewrite of your program

```
try:
    import msvcrt

    def getkey():
       return msvcrt.getch()


except ImportError:
    import sys
    import tty
    import termios
    def getkey():
        fd=sys.stdin.fileno()
        original_attributes =termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, original_attributes)
            return ch
```

This code says now, if we tried to import the library `msvcrt` and succeeded, then we will define a function `get_key` using the library, if failed; then we will define it again without using the library.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear on my first mail. I am new to stack Overflow, the code is fine. It might be copy paste issue. 
Once code is executed Pycharm is not working correct as I put an exception on it. Last night I found a workaround. Thanks for your help